# C++ templates - how to make from guessed pointer on datatype just data type

Tags: c++, templates

I have school project where I'm trying to make programme that can work with matrices. So far I have nonobject code, that can generate matrix and make basic operations. But at the beginning I have to define data type, which will be saved in matrices. So teacher recommand me to use templates for more versatility.

There are two parts where I need variable datatype.

1) Structure that define matrix - with pointer to pointer to datatype of matrix single element. (TType is define)

```
    struct TMatrix
    {
    TType **iData;
    unsigned iY, iX;
    };
```

2) Individual functions, for example function that allow to work with single elements.

```
        TType &At( TMatrix &aMat, const unsigned prvek_x, const unsigned prvek_y)
        {
        return (TType(aMat.iData[prvek_x][prvek_y]);
        }
```

First of all, in 1) how to use template in generating matrix structure? If I want to call it like this `TMatrix<double> amat = { nullptr, 0, 0 };`

Second thing, is it possible to get basic datatype from guesed pointer, so If I use in 2) something like this

```
        template <typename T>
        T &At(TMatrix &aMat, const unsigned prvek_x, const unsigned prvek_y)
```

how can I get `double` from `T` to substitute `TType` in return.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: You can use `decltype(TMatrix::iData)` to deduce the type.

Comment: Your 2) is wrong. The type of the first parameter should be `TMatrix<T>`, not just `TMatrix`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do both things with the template:

```
template <typename T>
struct TMatrix
{
    T **iData;
    unsigned iY, iX;
};

template <typename T>
T &At(TMatrix<T> &aMat, const unsigned prvek_x, const unsigned prvek_y) 
{
    return aMat.iData[prvek_x][prvek_y];
}
```

The explicit `TType` in the `At` function is not necessary because the `T` in `TMatrix<T>` and in the return type is the same as specified by the template.

You can test this code with this `main`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{

    TMatrix<double> amat = {nullptr, 0, 0};

    amat.iData = new double*[1];
    amat.iData[0] = new double[1];

    amat.iData[0][0] = 1;

    std::cout << At(amat, 0, 0) << std::endl;
    At(amat, 0, 0) = 5;
    std::cout << At(amat, 0, 0) << std::endl;

    delete[] amat.iData[0];
    delete[] amat.iData;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it help a lot.